# PHP array values into key values

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have below array

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>"; 
    print_r($row);
?>

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [contact] => ugin
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [contact] => gsGR
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [addtnlcontact] => ghjey
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [relation] => uncle
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [relation] => mrsyjsrky
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [relation] => cghjrtdj
        )

)
```

If i print `echo "<pre>"; print_r($row[0]);`

i have below array

```
Array
(
    [contact] => ugin
)
Array
(
    [relation] => uncle
)
```

i need above should be in $row[0] => contact => ugin
                                     relation => uncle

tried below code:

```
$addcont[] = $this->input->post(sheepItForm1_addtnlcontact);
$this->conditionloop($addcont[0],'contact');
$relation[] = $this->input->post(sheepItForm1_relationship);
$this->conditionloop($relation[0],'relation');
public function conditionloop($val,$name)
{
    foreach($val as $key => $res)
    {
        if(!empty($res)) {
            $row[$key][$name] = $res;
            //echo "<pre>"; print_r($row[$key]);
        }
    }
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($row[0]);
}
```

please help to solve this

Comment: jagan check the answer and let us know the final status?

Comment: 5 days no response , i am deleting my answer.

Comment: no its not working

Comment: what is your expected outcome? show us?

Comment: check my answer output link and let me know what's missing there?